# What's the best way to install Wordpress?

Tags: installation

Does anyone know what is considered the best way to install Wordpress.  Manually or perhaps is using something like Softaculous or QuickInstall the better approach?

Comment: It depends on the one who is installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WP-CLI's](https://wp-cli.org/) - `wp core install` - Runs the standard WordPress installation process.

> Creates the WordPress tables in the database using the URL, title, and default admin user details provided. Performs the famous 5 minute install in seconds or less.

```
$ wp core install --url=example.com --title=Example --admin_user=supervisor --admin_password=strongpassword --admin_email=info@example.com
Success: WordPress installed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server and enough permissions to install/run things on it, I'd recommend installing WordPress with the [Composer package manager](https://getcomposer.org/). Then updating WordPress to a newer version or rolling it back for bug-fixing is a breeze (log in to the server, edit one file, run one command), plus you'll only need one file to keep track of in source control (composer.json).

Another added benefit is that many free themes and plugins can be maintained with it as well, they're all listed on [WordPress Packagist](https://wpackagist.org/).

[Here's a good article](https://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/) walking through the steps necessary for this to happen. I should say it's not trivial to do that with an existing install; in that case, lots of care should be taken to avoid downtime.